# Finding shortest distance from one point to each polygon and the distance from that point of the polygon to any of the points in the polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, proximity

I'm trying to find the shortest distance from a point (point A uploaded as a CSV) to a polygon uploaded as a shapefile (polygon 1) and then the distance from that point of the polygon to any of the points in the polygon (e.g. point 1B, point 1C, point 1D inside polygon 1, uploaded as another CSV).

So the output expected is:
Point A -> closest point on Polygon 1 (P1): x km
P1 -> point 1B: x km
P1 -> point 1C: x km
P1 -> point 1D: x km

That's what I am trying to get to, also on a bigger scale, i.e. point A is always the same, but there are multiple polygons and multiple points in each polygon. At the end of the day, for each point I would like to have the shortest distance from the point A to the polygon that it sits within and then from there to the point itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assumed you have 3 layers called `BasePoint` (your point A), `Polygon`, and `PointsInPolygon`.

Depending on how you want the distance displayed, you can get the distance from each `Polygon` feature to `BasePoint` using the following expression:

```
with_variable('A',geometry(get_feature_by_id('BasePoint',1)),round(
    distance(
        closest_point(@geometry,@A),@A
    )/1000,2
)) || ' km'
```

And you can get the distance from each `PointsInPolygon` feature to its containing `Polygon` using the following similar expression:

```
with_variable('A',geometry(get_feature_by_id('BasePoint',1)),round(
    distance(
        closest_point(
            overlay_within('Polygon',@geometry,limit:=1)[0],@A
        ),@geometry
    )/1000,2
)) || ' km'
```

Output is as below.

If for some reason your BasePoint does not have a feature id of 1, you could replace this with `get_feature` eg `get_feature('BasePoint',"name",'A')`

[image]

If you add more polygons/points, the expressions continue to work:

[image]

**Note:** I used a geometry generator to create the lines joining the relevant features, and also for labelling. For example, the line from Point A to the Polygon layer can be visualised by:

```
with_variable('A',geometry(get_feature_by_id('BasePoint',1)),
make_line(closest_point(@geometry,@A),@A))
```

[image]

and labelled using rule-based labelling:

[image]

[image]

(The expressions are the same as for the distance and the creation of the line)

Comment: Thanks Tom! Your explanation was clear and it gave me the exact results that I was hoping to achieve. Can you please guide me on how to use a geometry generator to create the lines joining the relevant features? I've tried looking around and played with the symbology and geometry generator within that then some make line expression to no avail as I don't know what I'm doing. It would be great in helping me illustrate what is going on.

Comment: I've put a brief description on geometry generators in the answer - if you need more information, then best to ask a separate question (site policy is only one question per question!)